# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException for multi-threaded Java code

Tags: java, multithreading

I got ConcurrentModificationException at "String name = (String) keys.next();" line when I ran a java code in multi-threading. The part of the function that caused error is as follows:

```
 if (inputStr == null)
        return null;

    String tempStr = new String(inputStr);

    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    Iterator keys = props.keySet().iterator();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String name = (String) keys.next();
        String value = props.getProperty(name);

        //Build a pattern and compile it
        String patternStr = "%" + name + "%";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);

        // Replace all occurrences of pattern in input string
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tempStr);
        tempStr = matcher.replaceAll(value);
    }
```

The stacktrace detail is as follows:

> Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException  at
>   java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.next(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.pb.common.util.ResourceUtil.replaceWithSystemPropertyValues(ResourceUtil.java:350)
>     at
>   com.pb.common.calculator.ControlFileReader.searchAndReplaceWithEnv(ControlFileReader.java:610)
>     at
>   com.pb.common.calculator.ControlFileReader.readMatrixDataEntries(ControlFileReader.java:493)
>     at
>   com.pb.common.calculator.ControlFileReader.(ControlFileReader.java:109)
>     at
>   misc.UtilityExpressionCalculator.(UtilityExpressionCalculator.java:191)
>     at
>   misc.AbstractChoiceHandler.createUtilityExpressionCalculator(AbstractChoiceHandler.java:84)
>     at logSumCalculator.ModeChoiceModel.(ModeChoiceModel.java:41)
>     at logSumCalculator.ModeChoiceTask.run(ModeChoiceTask.java:59)

Is there a problem with how keys are iterated over?

Comment: Because you aren't modifying the `Properties` object here, the problem lies somewhere else. Do you set system properties in your application?

Comment: Yes, system properties are set in the application.

Comment: Then show us that code and explain how you intended it to synchronize with this code, because that's what's broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to synchronize on the Properties while iterating:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
synchronized(props) {
  // do work here ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the javadoc of [HashTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> if the Hashtable is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

It seems likely that you are calling `setProperty` on `System.getProperties()` in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the keys/contents while iterating or enumerating over the collection.

Create a temp holder for elements to be modified and then use it to make changes.